# How to properly login to use private images from GCR in Gitlab-ci?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to login into CGR and use some private docker images in Gitlab-ci runner.

I have made a new project in Google Cloud and activated the Google Cloud Registry API. I also made a new Service Account (IAM) in which I gave ownership permission to the previous Cloud Registry instance. Then I produced a json key. I tested the key with the following gitlab-ci configuration and in the local machine:

```
image: docker:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
auth:
  stage: auth
  script:
    - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < ./keyfile.json
```

It seems to be authenticated and authorised to push/pull images.

What I need to do is to have the following, I need to go to my private repository and use those images in the gitlab-ci runner. Something like this:

```
before_script:
    - docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < ./keyfile.json

build:
  stage: build
  image: gcr.io/image-repo/image
  script:
    - gradle clean build

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: gcr.io/image-repo/image
  script:
    - gradle publish
  only:
    - master
```

However, I keep on getting this error:

> Running with gitlab-runner 11.10.1 (1f513601)   on docker-auto-scale
>   0277ea0f Using Docker executor with image gcr.io/image-repo/image ...
>   Pulling docker image gcr.io/image-repo/image ... ERROR: Preparation
>   failed: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the
>   needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid
>   credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in:
>   https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
>   (executor_docker.go:168:0s) Will be retried in 3s ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I achieved a practical solution:

One needs to use the wind service to have a reseted docker configuration and then login, for instance in their local machine using:

```
docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://gcr.io < ./keyfile.json
```

Then, just just copy the configuration present in `~/.docker/config.json`
to the variable `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` in Gitlab CI and you're set to go.

Comment: what is "wind service"?

Comment: more info [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication)